# Button with both background image and color WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I have a button in my wpf app, looking like :

```
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" Height="28" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White">
     <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="cls_blk_btn.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Now as you can see the button has a background image, is it possible to have a background color keeping the image also ??

What i am trying to do is change the button's background color(keeping the image as it is) on mouse enter with this :

```
      <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF484A4D" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ParallelTimeline  >
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF57626C" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </ParallelTimeline>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```

The problem is, as the background is an image, i get exceptions while trying to change the color...Any help in keeping the image as it is and changing the backColor ???

**THIS IS WHAT I JUST TRIED**

```
    <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="resources\c_ml.bmp" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\c_mo.bmp" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
```

But it gives me **'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.'** in line 45.The lines throwing the exceptions are:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="resources\c_ml.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

**I FIXED MY SECOND ERROR BUT HAVE A NEW PROBLEM**

The second error occured because i didn't include the pictures in my project.After including, i have a new problem. Now , on mouse over, The button becomes white, i mean it changes it's Background color instead of changing the image...What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED IT MYSELF**

```
    <Button.Content>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Name="image1"  Source="pack://application:,,,/OffPo Diagnostic Tool;component/resources/c_ml.bmp" Stretch="Fill" >
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <Image Name="image2" Source="pack://application:,,,/OffPo Diagnostic Tool;component/resources/c_mo.bmp" Stretch="Fill" >
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>                   
    </StackPanel>
</Button.Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to put the Image in background? If you just want to show an Image with background in the button, it will be lot easier to put the Image in Button.Content and animate the background, e.g.:

```
<Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Height="280" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image  Source="image.png" Stretch="None" />
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF57626C" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FF484A4D" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ParallelTimeline  >
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FF57626C" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </ParallelTimeline>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: See my own solution.I fixed the problem, but have a new problem, now the button has a border outta nowhere, how do i fix that ???

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm not following, are you trying to change the background or the image on mouse entering?

Comment: What i firstly wanted was to keep the image but also have a background color(like winforms) of the button so that i can change the background color keeping the image as it is. I found it very difficult so moved on to changing the image on mouseEnter/MouseOver . My  solution says that. But the problem with my solution/answer is, the button now has a white border which i have no idea where it came from...any fix on how to remove those borders???

Comment: hey wait!!!!!! I guess your solution is perfect!!!!!...Let me try it !!!!!!! i'm sorry i din't see it the first time

Comment: now I understand your problem about the border. It's the default behavior of Button, to suppress that you need to modify the default ControlTemplate of Button control. See my updated answer.